# Use switch cases based on condition

Tags: ios, swift

I have made a file called `Constants.swift`. Within this, I have made a class like so...

```
public class WebServices {
    static let getMyPlants : String = "plant/getPlants"
    static let getMyOrganizations: String = "organization/getOrganizations"
}
```

Now whenever, I use an api anywhere in my project, I do `Webservices.getMyPlants`.

Now I also have a base-url for each of the API's. That is mentioned below `public class WebServices....` like so..

```
struct envDev {
    var BASEURL : String = "http://api-proj-dev.ii.the-co.com/api/"

}
```

Now, the base-url for `Webservices.getMyOrganizations` is different. I want to use a condition within `struct envDev` that if I have selected `Webservices.getMyOrganizations`, then I can give a different `BASEURL`. Something like...

```
 //The below code isn't right. I just wrote it to represent the kind of solution I wish to have. 

    struct envDev {
            var BASEURL : String = "http://api-proj-dev.ii.the-co.com/api/"

            if Webservices.getMyOrganizations {
              var BASEURL : String = "http://my second base-url.." 
            }
        }
```

**EDIT 1** Giving below the signature of `APIHelper`

```
class APIHelper: NSObject {


    var API: NSString

    var json: NSString

    var receivedJSON: NSString?

    var arrResult: NSMutableArray = []

    let esmatBaseUrl = AppDelegate().currentUser //This is given in AppDelegate as `var currentUser = envDev()`
()
```

**EDIT 2** Inclusion of `baseUrl` computed property in APIHelper & the error.

```
class APIHelper: NSObject {


        var API: NSString

        var json: NSString

        var receivedJSON: NSString?

        var arrResult: NSMutableArray = []

        let esmatBaseUrl = AppDelegate().currentUser //This is given in AppDelegate as `var currentUser = envDev()`
    ()

        var baseUrl: String {
        esmatBaseUrl.baseUrl(forApi: API as String) // Here I'm getting the error as `Value of type 'envDev' has no member 'baseUrl'`
    }
```

Comment: "...that if I have selected `Webservices.getMyOrganizations`..." What do you mean by this? Can you show how you can "select"  `Webservices.getMyOrganizations`?

Comment: I meant to say if I want to call the `getMyOrganizations` API then. While calling the API it would look like so..`APIHelper(API: WebServices.getMyOrganizations as NSString, .....`

Comment: Are you looking for Environment setup? Because we normally change base urls when we change the environment like production, staging..

Comment: Actually @Rob, in my current project a set of API's have a certain base url while the remaining set has a different base-url...That's why.. And that too within the same environment...

Comment: And then you would pass the `BASEURL` as the second parameter? And you want `BASEURL`'s value to be automatically resolved depending on the first parameter you passed? Can you rewrite `APIHelper` so that it accepts a `URL` instead?

Comment: Yes @Sweeper..But rewriting `APIHelper` will cause many changes..:(

Comment: Okay... can you show the signature of `APIHelper`? You should [edit] your question and include all the other details you told me as well.

Comment: Have edited the question by adding the signature of APIHelper @Sweeper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`envDev` has no way of knowing what happens in `APIHelper`, so you need a way to pass in the `API` from `APIHelper` to `envDev`. This means that `BASEURL` should not be a property, but a method:

```
func baseUrl(forApi api: String) -> String {
    switch api {
    case WebServices.getMyPlants: return "some url"
    case WebServices.getMyOrganizations: return "some other url"
    default: fatalError()
    }
}
```

Then in `APIHelper`, you can add a `baseUrl` computed property that calls the above method:

```
var baseUrl: String {
    esmatBaseUrl.baseUrl(forApi: API as String)
}
```

This would mean that you need to change all occurrences of `esmatBaseUrl.BASEURL` in your existing code to just `baseUrl`.

Also, I would suggest not using `NSString`, `NSArray`, etc in Swift. You should their Swift counterparts: `String` and `[T]`.

Comment: I have implemented what you suggested @Sweeper. But I'm getting an error. Have edited the question to show the inclusion of `baseUrl` computed property in APIHelper and have also highlighted the error..

Comment: @user13032222 Did you replace the `BASEURL` property with the `baseUrl` method (first code snippet in my answer)? Please don't just apply part of my answer.

Comment: Yes @Sweeper..I had included it in my `Constants` class where I had my `public class WebServices..` defined.

Comment: @user13032222 No, you should replace `BASEURL` with it, which means you should delete `BASEURL`, and put `baseUrl` in the `envDev` struct.

Comment: Ok @Sweeper. You mean I should add the baseUrl computed property within `envDev` struct..?

Comment: @user13032222 Yes, that is what I said. And this would be a breaking change. Anywhere you used `APIHelper. esmatBaseUrl.BASEURL`, you will need to change to `APIHelper.baseUrl`.

Comment: Sure @Sweeper. No my struct `envDev` looks like so..`var baseUrl: String {
        APIHelper.esmatBaseUrl.baseUrl(forApi: API as String)
      }`

Comment: But I get the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'API'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215295/discussion-between-sweeper-and-user13032222).

Answer (score 1):

I understood your query. You want to create an ENUM for your server-environment's, instead of hard-coding baseUrl's you probably want to use ENUMS to select different environments, right.

So accordingly, I've created an ENUM for you to add different server-environments so it will be feasible for you to use it frequently every-where.

```
private enum ServerEnv: String {
    case stage, prod, test, my_plants, my_organization

    var domainValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .test, .my_plants: return "http://api-testing-proj-dev.ii.the-co.com/api/"
        case .stage: return "http://api-staging-proj-dev.ii.the-co.com/api/"
        case .prod: return "http://api-production-proj-dev.ii.the-co.com/api/"
        case .my_organization: return "http://api-my_organization-proj-dev.ii.the-co.com/api/"
        }
    }
}
```

**Example :**

```
 let baseUrl = ServerEnv.my_organization.domainValue

 Output => baseURL = "http://api-my_organization-proj-dev.ii.the-co.com/api/"

let baseUrl = ServerEnv.my_plants.domainValue

 Output => baseURL = "http://api-testing-proj-dev.ii.the-co.com/api/"
```

I hope, I've solved your query here.

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: Actually Ashish, I have many API's (say 10). And for 5 I have one base url and for the other 5 I have a different base-url.

Comment: You can combine cases

Comment: So what, you required? You can explain bit more in your question with example.

Comment: @TalCohen Please check my solution, I've updated it accordingly - what you showed., is it right?